# Lost BIOS password, what are my options?

Tags: boot, bios

I have a Lenovo ThinkPad T420s. On it I've been running Kubuntu since I got it 3 years ago. I bought an SSD to replace the spinning disk. When I swapped the disks and put in my bootable Kubuntu USB to make a fresh OS install, I found out that apparently the BIOS password I set is not in my keychain. And I disabled boot from USB in the BIOS. Oops.

Is it still somehow possible to switch disks and do a new OS install?

I'm happy to post additional details, though am presently not sure what would be relevant.

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is factory default your BIOS. How this is done varies from system to system, depending on the motherboard vendor and model.

Two of the more common methods:

1. Use a CMOS flash jumper on the motherboard
2. Remove the CMOS battery

I recommend contacting the hardware vendor for instructions on how to do this on your machine